# Multiple Images in a Loop & canvas placement

Tags: fabricjs

I am encountering a strange situation when using FabricJS.

1) An AJAX call is made to get a list of images with their canvas location data i.e. X & Y. There are many such images in the list.
2) In the javascript code I have loop that loops each image and puts them on the canvas.
3) The issue is that the all the images are stacked over one another as if all the images get the coordinates of the first image.

Any ideas what might be happening?

Is there a way to know when the first image is loaded on the canvas and only then load the next image, like callback sort.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop pass the coordinates into closure function and use fabric.image.fromurl method. Like the code from examples and tutorials

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('my_image.png', function(oImg) {
  // scale image down, and flip it, before adding it onto canvas
  oImg.scale(0.5).setFlipX(true);
  canvas.add(oImg);
});
```

Comment: I have tried this but does not work, please view the code i am using here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442299/images-in-a-loop-with-fabricjs

Comment: i wrote. please use a closure, this exactly the issue there. Read what is a closure in javascript. i will post some code in the new thread to help you out