# Images in a loop with FabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs and I have a JSON list of images. each element represents an image with info such as left, top etc for each image. in my javascript code I have the following

```
    for (var j = 0; j < ChrImages.d.length; j++) {

    var obj = ChrImages.d[j];

    fabric.util.loadImage(obj.URL, function (img) {
        var customImage = new fabric.CustomImage(img, { name: obj.Name, rot: obj.Rotation, rawURL: obj.RawURL, belongsto: obj.BelongsTo,left:obj.PosX,top:obj.PosY,angle:obj.Rotation });
        //customImage.set({
        //    left: obj.PosX,
        //    top: obj.PosY,
        //    angle: obj.Rotation,
        //    lockScalingX: true,
        //    lockScalingY: true,
        //    perPixelTargetFind: true,
        //});
     //   customImage.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.RemoveWhite());
        canvas.add(customImage);
        groupWorkingChromosomeImages.add(customImage);
    });

    }
```

the issue I am having is that all the images are stacked over one another. it seems all images get the same left and top.

I have check to make sure that the JSON list is accurate. Also, I need to use a custom class as my images have additional attributes.

Can someone please let me know why adding images in the tight loop is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable  **obj** is not in the same scope of the loadImage function, so this gives you unexpected results cause you can't control when loadImage fires. Probably it fires much after your **for** loop finishes.

use this code and tell me if it helped:

```
for (var j = 0; j < ChrImages.d.length; j++) {
    var currentObj = ChrImages.d[j];

    //closure, create a scope for specific variables
    (function (obj) {
        fabric.util.loadImage(obj.URL, function (img) {
            var customImage = new fabric.CustomImage(img, {
                name: obj.Name,
                rot: obj.Rotation,
                rawURL: obj.RawURL,
                belongsto: obj.BelongsTo,
                left: obj.PosX,
                top: obj.PosY,
                angle: obj.Rotation
            });
            canvas.add(customImage);
            groupWorkingChromosomeImages.add(customImage);
        });

    })(currentObj);

}
```

i wrapped your loadImage function so it will use the right obj instance inside closure, tell me if it works.

cheers