# Loading Fabric.js images in a loop

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using Fabric.js to (among other things) load images in a loop, and position them accordingly.  There seems to be some sort of timing/refreshing issue - the following code works:

```
for (var x = 0; x < rewardImages.length; x++) {

    //add reward sticker:
    if (rewardPHPositions[x] != undefined) {
        fabric.Image.fromURL(rewardImages[x], function (oImg) {
            canvas.add(oImg); canvas.renderAll();
        }, { "height": 128, "width": 128, "left": rewardPHPositions[x][0], "top": rewardPHPositions[x][1], "category": "RewardSticker" });
    }
    canvas.renderAll();

    alert(x.toString());

}
```

but omitting the alert results in no images being loaded.  It's almost as if there's a delay needed or some blocking required to slow the execution of the loop down.  I thought that as long as I had the canvas.add call in the callback (which should only run when the image has been loaded) I should have been fine, but something is missing evidently.

I've tried moving the code out into a closure as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442299/images-in-a-loop-with-fabricjs), and I've tried experimenting with different placements for the renderAll call, but to no avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your code seems to be working for a fiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/2w9k0e77/ It will be easier to identify your problem if you can create a fiddle or post whole code here. I am sure you are changing some flags for the canvas, since you need to call canvas.renderAll() on object addition (which is not required in default properties).